# IPtables allow iprange gives error (LINUX)

Tags: linux, iptables

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m iprange --src -range 162.211.152.1-162.211.152.255 -j ACCEPT
Bad argument `162.211.152.1-162.211.152.255'
```

As title suggests this iprange gives an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should not be any space between "--src -range".

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m iprange --src-range 162.211.152.1-162.211.152.254 -j ACCEPT
```